# Why is deinit not called until UIView is added to parent again?

Tags: swift, memory, memory-leaks, swift3, deinit

I have a UIView that am adding to a UIViewController and am generally testing de-initialization to make sure I am doing things right. But when I don't set the variable in my viewController to nil and only use .removeFromSuperView() , the deinit() method  in UIView won't be called until I add the UIView another time then its called. But if I use removeFromSuperView() and set the variable to nil then deinit() is called right away. Why is that?

Here's UIView() class:

```
class TestView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        print("init is happneing")
    }

    deinit {
        print("de init is happneing")
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here's the parent ViewController :

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController { 
 var tstview  : TestView?


  //adding the UIView by tapping on a button 
 @IBAction func addView(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let test = TestView()
        tstview = test
        tstview?.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 60, width: self.view.frame.width-100, height: self.view.frame.height-200)
        tstview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.addSubview(tstview!)  
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()  
    }

    //removing UIView by touching elsewhere 
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
         tstview?.removeFromSuperview()
      //  tstview = nil

    }


}
```

Comment: Hi.  Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`deinit` is called when no one is referencing the object. If you don't set `tstview` to `nil`, your MyViewController is still referencing it, thus `deinit` won't be called. When you call `addView`, the statement `tstview = test` finally removes the last reference to the old view, thus triggering the deinitializer.

You can read more about the concept of deinitialization in the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html).

---

If you want to be notified as soon as the view is detached, [override `willMove(toSuperview:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622629-willmove) instead.

```
class TestView: UIView {
    ...
    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        if newSuperview == nil {
            print("removed from parent")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I want to make sure I don't leave any leak , which in that case as I understand willMove toSuperview won't help. I'm trying to understand why removeFromSuperview() doesn't deinit until I add another instance of the UIView() to my parent controller because then and only then I see deinit being called. I have looked at the docs but can't find the reason.