# willMove vs init, when to use which?

Tags: ios, swift

As I'm creating a custom `UITextField`, i.e. `CurrencyTextField` as per [How to input currency format on a text field (from right to left) using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782982/how-to-input-currency-format-on-a-text-field-from-right-to-left-using-swift/29783546#29783546). I could set the configuration in `willMove` function as below

```
    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        Formatter.currency.locale = locale
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        keyboardType = .numberPad
        textAlignment = .right
        sendActions(for: .editingChanged)
    }
```

However, as I previously learn, we could also set it during `init` as below instead of using `willMove`

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        Formatter.currency.locale = locale
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        keyboardType = .numberPad
        textAlignment = .right
        sendActions(for: .editingChanged)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

They seems to behave the same for my case. So I'm not sure when should I use `init`, and when should `willMove`?

I saw this post on `deinit` vs `willMove` in [Why is deinit not called until UIView is added to parent again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42598996/why-is-deinit-not-called-until-uiview-is-added-to-parent-again). That's well explained for `deinit` vs `willMove`, but not clear my question on `init` vs `willMove`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`willMove` can be called multiple times (whenever the view's super view changes). `init` is only called *once* **ever**.

The main question for you to consider is:

> Do you want your code to run only once, or every time the view's super view changes?

For example, the below code will print `will move called` three times:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        print("will move called")
    }
}

let view1 = UIView()
let view2 = UIView()
let myView = MyView()
view1.addSubview(myView) //*
myView.removeFromSuperview() //*
view2.addSubview(myView) //*
```

Every line marked with `*` will cause `willMove` to be called. Note that even removing the view from its superview calls `willMove`, since it "moves to a new super view of `nil`".

For your specific case though,

```
Formatter.currency.locale = locale
addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
keyboardType = .numberPad
textAlignment = .right
sendActions(for: .editingChanged)
```

I don't think executing the above code more than once makes much of a difference, so putting it in either method works fine.

---

Another difference is that `init` is called immediately after the view is created, while the first call of `willMove` does not happen until the view is added to a superview. This might make a difference in some rare cases.

Comment: Nicely explained. Thank you!